# What are some elegant ways to abstract out repetitive exception handling in python?

Tags: python, exception

When handling exceptions in python, I find myself repeating code quite often.  The basic pattern is something of the form:

```
try:
  action_here()
except CommonException1:
  Action_always_taken_for_CommonException1()
except CommonException2:
  Action_always_taken_for_CommonException2()
except Exception:
  Default_action_always_taken()
```

What I would like to do is to some how abstract this repetitive code out to a function or class.  I know one way to do it is to call an exception handling function with the exception object, such as:

```
try:
  action_here()
except Exception as e:
  handle_exception(e)
```

Then in this function determine the exception based on class.

```
def handle_exception(e):
  if type(e) == type(CommonException1()):
    Action_always_taken_for_CommonException1()
  elif type(e) == type(CommonException2()):
    Action_always_taken_for_CommonException2())
  else:
    Default_action_always_taken()
```

This, however, feels clunky and inelegant.  So my question is, what are some other alternatives to handling repetitive exception handling?

Comment: That seems as elegant as it can get. What were you thinking of using?

Comment: @Blender My solution was the only viable solution I had come up with.  I was asking to see if anyone knew of a better solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This situation is one of the main use cases for context managers and the with statement:

```
from __future__ import with_statement # Needed in 2.5, but not in 2.6 or later

from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def handle_exceptions():
    try:
        yield # Body of the with statement effectively runs here
    except CommonException1:
        Action_always_taken_for_CommonException1()
    except CommonException2:
        Action_always_taken_for_CommonException2()
    except Exception:
        Default_action_always_taken()

# Used as follows
with handle_exceptions():
    action_here()
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you dislike the repeated `if` / `elseif` blocks, you could put your handles in a dict, keyed by type:

```
handlers = { type(CommonException1()) : Action_always_taken_forCommonException1,
             type(CommonException2()) : Action_always_taken_forCommonException2 }

def handle_exception(te):
  if te in handlers:
    handlers[te]()
  else:
    Default_action()
```

Which you could then run with:

```
try:
  action_here()
except Exception as e:
  handle_exception(type(e))
```

---

**In addition:** If you find yourself writing these try blocks frequently, then you could write your own context manager (see [here](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#writing-context-managers)). At the `action_here()` side, your code would then look like this:

```
with my_error_handling_context():
  action_here1()
  action_here2()
```

In this case, the `handle_exception` code would essentially be your context manager's `__exit__` method (which will always get passed any exceptions raised during the with block).

Comment: The context manager is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Although a solution using a context manager (as proposed by others) is the most elegant, and would be what I would recommend too, I'd like to point out that your `handle_exception` function could be written more elegantly by re-raising the exception:

```
def handle_exception(e):
  try:
    raise e
  except CommonException1:
    Action_always_taken_for_CommonException1()
  except CommonException2:
    Action_always_taken_for_CommonException2()
  except Exception:
    Default_action_always_taken()
```

Comment: Thanks, I never would of thought of that myself.